# To expect only one return based on conditions from queryset filter

Tags: django

Based on my Queryset with filter I expect only one value to be returned

Currently we use max aggregation to make sure only one value is returned

```
lease_dict = LeaseTenant.objects.filter(tenat_id=self.id, is_active = True).aggregate(Max('id'))
```

Never had issue with it , but  it is not best way since if suddenly there is will be some error in the system and more then value will exist the Max will hide the issue.

What is the better alternative ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a get to force a single result :)

```
lease_dict = LeaseTenant.objects.get(tenat_id=self.id, is_active=True)
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get

If no results are returned it will raise a `LeaseTenant.object.DoesNotExist`. And if multiple results are returned it will raise a [`MultipleObjectsReturned`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use filter instead of get lease_dict = LeaseTenant.objects.filter(tenat_id=self.id, is_active=True)[0]